# What is the subtle purpose for writing Verilog code this way instead of direct continuous assignment?

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment, delay, vivado

I saw the following Verilog code in the top-most simulation test-bench source file `sim_tb_top.v` generated automatically by Example Design of MIG memory controller in Xilinx Vivado:

```
localparam real TPROP_PCB_CTRL     = 0.00;
                   // Delay for Address and Ctrl signals
wire [0:0] ddr3_cs_n_fpga;
reg [0:0] ddr3_cs_n_sdram_tmp;
wire [0:0] ddr3_cs_n_sdram;

always @( * )
    ddr3_cs_n_sdram_tmp   <=  #(TPROP_PCB_CTRL) ddr3_cs_n_fpga;
assign ddr3_cs_n_sdram =  ddr3_cs_n_sdram_tmp;
```

I don't understand why the generated source code does not just use a direct continuous assignment:

```
assign ddr3_cs_n_sdram = #(TPROP_PCB_CTRL) ddr3_cs_n_fpga;
```

I cannot see the difference of the two.  Does the generated code in `sim_tb_top.v` which uses a combinational `always` block have some special subtle purpose over a direct continuous assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `always` block with a nonblocking assignment performs *transport* delay, whereas the continuous assignment performs *inertial* delay.

*Transport* delay means the signals RHS of the assignment can change faster than the assignment delay without any loss in intermediate values.

*Inertial* delay means if the signals on the RHS of the assignment change faster than the assignment delay, those intermediate values will get suppressed; a new assignment cannot happen until the next scheduled assignment happens. A blocking assignment in the `always` block could have produce the same effect, but continuous assignments always have inertial delay.

I'm assuming the delays are not always 0.0 and overwritten by SDF or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case, the 2 code styles are comparable.  However, it is surprising that the generated code uses a nonblocking assignment (`<=`) instead of a blocking assignment (`=`); this does not adhere to good coding style.

Generally speaking, continuous assignments are a good coding style when the logic they represent is simple.  However, if the logic becomes complex, it sometimes makes the code difficult to understand if you try to cram too much into a continuous assignment.  In that case, the design can be easier to understand using an `always` block, where the logic can be described more naturally using `if/else` and `case` statements and the like.

It is not apparent why the generator tool chooses one style over the other.  Perhaps the tool itself was easier to implement by generating the `always` block style of code when there is a delay specified.  Perhaps the tool only uses a continuous assignment for trivial `a = b` assignments.